# Truffle HDWalletProvider alternative?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, truffle

Is there any other alternative to HDWalletProvider that imports MetaMask's accounts via the 12 word mnemonic? Thanks in advance for the info.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to import your accounts using HDWalletProvider than the only alternative I can think of is using [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org) and a wallet like MetaMask to deploy your contracts.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new alternative using truffle dashboard: "connect Truffle Dashboard to your wallet the same way you would for any other dapp"

for more details see https://trufflesuite.com/blog/introducing-truffle-dashboard/